# Is it possible to catch all selector calls and redirect them at runtime

Tags: objective-c

I want to do something a little hacky.

When we try and call a method on a class where isn't defined we usually get an error, e.g.

```
// We get a undefined selector callback
[myClass someUndefinedMethod];
```

I want to add something into `MyClass` that catches all these undefined method calls and deals with it.  Is this possible?

I want something like this, but which will intercept all method calls:

```
@implementation MyClass

    - (void) performSelector(SEL):selector {

          // Check if the method exists
          if (![self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
              // Handle unimplemeted selector
              NSLog(@"No method called %@", selector);
          } 

          // Otherwise proced as normal
          else {
              [super performSelector:selector];
          }
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just override the [`doesNotRecognizeSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/doesNotRecognizeSelector:) method on NSObject (assuming you're inheriting from it, which you should be)?

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for, I knew there would be a way.

Comment: @paulbailey You got lucky, 2 minutes after me with exactly the same answer and your answer was accepted :)

Answer (score 7):

Override method:
`-[MyClass doesNotRecognizeSelector:]`
and call whatever you want.

This is what `NSManagedObject` is doing to get/set core data properties.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear whether you are trying to intercept messages sent to a class or to an instance of a class. In any case perhaps looking into / searching on the topics of 'message forwarding' and 'forwarding messages'. Also see NSObject's forwardInvocation and the section of Apple's runtime pgmg guide on message forwarding 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

These got me to the answer I was looking for and I did not see them mentioned elsewhere on this question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try and make a new category for "NSObject" and overwrite that specific method like that. Anyway, keep in mind that Apple recommends not using categories to overwrite methods, but to add new functionality, so it's a bit hackish. However, I'm not sure that will get rid of the warnning...